# Returning back to the beginning of a block of code? C# CMD App

Tags: c#, loops

I need to know how to go back to the start of a cmd app (like when I start the app) Here is what I have:

```
using System;

namespace Convo-
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Console.WriteLine("Friend- How is your day going?");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("You- Good = 1" +
                " / Bad = 2");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyinfo.KeyChar == '1')

            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Friend- That's very nice!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Friend- Im sorry is there anything I can do?");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("(Don't like your choice go back by clicking 3)");

            bool running = true;


          if (keyinfo.KeyChar == '3')
            {
                //here is where i need the go back function

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare functions which can be called after executing the end of your app.. i.e, `onStart`, `onMiddle`, `onEnd`. in your `Main` program, call the `onStart` which then executes the `onMIddle` and `onEnd` functions.. then call `onStart` on your will

Comment: You could make it a method and let it call itself (recursion) or you could use a do/while loop.

Comment: You move your code into [methods (functions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) then use [loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/iteration-statements) to repeat sections of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most basic units of re-use in programming is the function.

By placing the code within a function, we can call it again easily (the example below shows the function calling itself, which re-starts the conversation).

```
using System;

namespace Convo-
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartConversation();
        }

        private static void StartConversation()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Console.WriteLine("Friend- How is your day going?");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("You- Good = 1" +
                " / Bad = 2");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            if (keyinfo.KeyChar == '1')

            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Friend- That's very nice!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Friend- Im sorry is there anything I can do?");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("(Don't like your choice go back by clicking 3)");

            bool running = true;


          if (keyinfo.KeyChar == '3')
            {
                //here is where i need the go back function
                StartConversation();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And to add some additional clarity, I have deliberately undertaken "one single move" in the game of chess that is...

> Extract 'til you drop

Which means you need to continue to refactor out methods that have a single responsibility to make your code more readable.